# Double linebreak fails with matplotlib and xkcd style

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

The following python3 code does not work, because of the **double** linebreak in line 9:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.xkcd()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.text(4, 400, '-> 1 Pig ~ 150 kg\n\n-> Butching => 80 to 100 kg meat')
plt.axis([0, 7, 0, 2000])
plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5], [0,400,800,1200,1600, 2000])
ax.set_ylim([0, 2000])
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.show()
```

But if I remove the `plt.xkcd()` line, then everything works fine even with the double linebreak.
Does anyone now why?
Is it a bug or is there any workaround?

**My Setup:**
Windows 7 amd64, 
python 3.3, 
numpy 1.8, 
matplotlib 1.3.1

Comment: and does it work with the plt.xkcd line, if you remove the double linebreak? are you sure it is because of the double linebreak? -cant reproduce since my version of matplotlib is too low n gives error at plt.xkcd()-

Comment: @mutzmatron I fixed his code and the error is correctly reported...I reproduced here

Comment: I opened [this issue in matplotlib's issue tracker on GitHub...](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2687)

Comment: `xkcd` is a standrad component of `matplotlib` since version 1.3. I can also reproduce the error (works with either removing the double line break or the `plt.xkcd()`).

Answer (score 1):

Two hacks to fix this:

- replace the double newline with "\n.\n" (i.e. add a small dot)

  ```
  plt.text(4, 400, '-> 1 Pig ~ 150 kg\n.\n-> Butching => 80 to 100 kg meat')
  ```
- Split your multiline text into multiple calls to text (best result)

  ```
  plt.text(4, 400, '-> 1 Pig ~ 150 kg')
  plt.text(4, 240, '-> Butching => 80 to 100 kg meat')
  ```

  Or

  ```
  text = '-> 1 Pig ~ 150 kg\n\n-> Butching => 80 to 100 kg meat'
  for il, l in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
      plt.text(4, 400-80*il, l)
  ```

Comment: Your first example is bad because of the dot. Even a secured whitespace (\xA0) between those \n wont work. The other two are good, but don't scale with my textsize, so it is not an ultimate solution.

Comment: Agreed - for a more complete fix you could add the textsize parameter and use that to scale the spacing (instead of the arbitrary value of 80 I used). Again, these are mainly workarounds for a specific problem, not bugfixes worthy of being added to the matplotlib codebase :)

Comment: what happens if you just put a space between the `\n`?

Comment: @tcaswell: Tried that, doesn't work - the last line isn't shown.